# PHP time() function giving me the wrong time

Tags: php, datetime

I am using the following PHP code to get the current time.

```
$time = time();
echo date('h:m:s A',$time);
```

The time returned is the wrong time.  The current time is `05:14:33` PM on my computer and this function is showing `12:03:02` PM.

Why it is giving the wrong time and how can I get PHP to give the right time?

Comment: [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: what server stack do you use to run this code? XAMPP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: FYI `m` represents the month, not the minutes. Your looking for `i`. Please see the [PHP Date Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: use this date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi"); inside function you have to define your time zone my is Asia/Karachi

Answer (score 6):

`time()` gives the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC. This is read from the internal clock in your OS/computer. `date()` gives you the date on a timestamp in the default **timezone**.

Use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and [`date_default_timezone_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) to check/set the correct timezone.

Alternatively you can set the default timezone in your `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Please set your timezone if you have errors on your current time. 
Here you can find more information about it ...
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Here you can find all timezones:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php